# Javascript cant set previous value to variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I have function as follows:

```
function isAttachedDataChanged(){
        if(attachedDataOld != interaction.attachedData){
                console.log("VARIABLE IS CHANGED");
        }
}
```

And I run this function like that, and after run I set `attachedDataOld` with new values:

```
isAttachedDataChanged(); 
attachedDataOld = interaction.attachedData;
```

When I run this first time `attachedDataOld` is empty, so it is good, but when I run this next times `attachedDataOld` is setted not with previous value but with a present value. So it is working like:
First make this:`attachedDataOld = interaction.attachedData;`
And next do this: `isAttachedDataChanged();`

Comment: If `interaction.attachedData` is an object and not a pure value, you're binding the two objects to the same one.

Comment: yes interaction is an object. 'var interaction = {/*some values*/attachedData:{}}'

Comment: Are you changing `interaction.attachedData` anywhere? I am not really sure what your problem is but it looks like the console will only log  'VARIABLE IS CHANGED' the first time and after that `attachedDataOld` `interaction.attachedData` are the same so nothing is logged.

Comment: Then you'd check for a unique id, hash or whatever instead of the object itself. As I previously said, when you say myVar = anObject, you're changing its pointer, not its value.

Comment: thanks, I dont see that what I do :) Now its working by 'var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);'

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets say that your script is starting, its calling isAttachedDataChange(), attachedDataOld is not set, your function end and attachedDataOld is equal to interaction.attachedData. How you expect in the second time that your function is called your if statement to return true? You have set attachedDataOld=interaction.attachedData.